# Animating text input height

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate a text inputs height. I can do *sort of* achieve this with animate() on focus and remove on blur. 
The problem is that it only moves the bottom border when I would like to move both the bottom AND the top equally.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input[type=text]").on("focus", function(){
          $(this).animate({height:40}, 200);
           }).blur(function(){
          $(this).animate({height:10}, 200);
          })
      });
```

Code here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/RichieBrennan/pen/PJdvjB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS alone and no javascript if you like.

In the example below I've put an input into a centered flex box simply to allow the height to expand both vertically up and down.  Setting the transform origin Y axis to 50% ensures when it changes it, does so from the center, and just doesn't grow 'downwards'.  The example is slightly exaggerated, and you'd need to adjust it to your needs.

```css
#formWrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100px;
}

input {
  height: 12px;
  transform-origin: 50% left;
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-out;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}

input:focus {
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="formWrapper">
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think I will go with this solution. I'd still be interested in knowing how it is done with Jquery just out of interest but your way does exactly what I need. Thanks Robert!

Comment: I believe you could still apply the transform origin property in CSS and do the animate with javascript if you wanted to but it would be totally unnecessary.  CSS transitions are much cleaner and smoother anyway because you can take advantage of hardware acceleration.  Always try and go with CSS animations where you can over something like jquery. Cheers.